# Why do I have different versions of npm in different windows directories?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to get an angular2 application started, which needs at least npm 3.x.x, so I load up cmd and I run:

```
>f:
>cd f:\code\angular2app
>npm -v
2.11.2
```

then I run

```
>c:
>cd c:\Users\my.name\AppData\Roaming\npm
>npm -v
3.9.5
```

What's causing the difference in the npm version for these 2 directories?
How can I run `npm install npm -g` in the angular2app directory to actually install the latest version globally?

Comment: you probably have installed it 2 times in those directories without installing it globally, so first delete both local versions and then reinstall it globally.

Comment: @Christophvh that solved what I needed, if you add that as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have installed npm two seperate times inside those directories. Delete both local versions and then reinstall npm globally.